# RIA paging with custom data layer

Tags: paging, wcf-ria-services, legacy-database

We're using a custom data access layer to read our domain objects (customers, orders, etc) from a database. This data access layer does not support paging or sorting.

We want to publish parts of the data (for instance customers) to a Silverlight client, using WCF RIA Services. In the client, we want to display a data grid with paging.

Now, in our RIA DomainService, we will have a function such as

```
IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
   List<Customer> customers = OurPersisteceLayer.GetAllCustomers();
   return customers.AsQueryable()
}
```

This function will read all customer records from the database. I assume RIA can't do any form of server-side paging in this scenario - We will always read all customers when the function is called.

My questions are:

Will RIA cache the customer list in the client (and call GetCustomers only once), or will it execute the operation every time a user moves to the next page in the data grid?

In my scenario, the operation may take 5 seconds to execute which would be acceptable if it's done once, but not if it takes 5 seconds every time the user wants to move to a new page in the data grid.

Is there some good solution/pattern/method to use when using RIA to access a legacy data access layer and you want to use paging?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using DomainDataSource on the client side for paging. It essentially just calls `Skip` and `Take` on the IQueryable. So my hunch is since you are always getting all customers with each call to `GetCustomers`, that each page operation will cause you to get all the customers each time. The DDS is assuming its call to `Skip` and `Take` will get composed into the LINQ query and ultimately made on the datasource itself.